# Хочу стилизовать одинаковые h2 на всей странице, как лучше это сделать?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

друзья. У меня есть много одинаковых h2-h3 заголовков на сайте. Содержатся они в разных блоках(секциях). Стилизованы они все по одному: один размер шрифта, line-height и т.д. То есть, они абсолютно идентичные. Создавал название классов я по бэму, то есть, к примеру: header__title - для хедера, shop__title - для магазина и т.д И вот тут вопрос, мне стоит эти заголовки все собрать под кучку в CSS и задать им один стиль, к примеру:

```
.header__title,
.shop__title {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Или же лучше просто создать какой-то отдельный класс, который я буду присваивать этим тегам, допустим:

```
<h2 class="header__title main-title">Привет</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если все идентичные, почему бы просто не юзать:

```
h2{
 font-size: 32px;
}
```

А если есть необходимость конкретно в определенном блоке менять, то:

Допустим у вас в `.html` так:

```
<div class = 'container'>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
</div>
<div class = 'new_container'>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
</div>
```

То `.css` может быть таким:

```
.container h2{
    font-size: 32px;
}

.new_container h2{
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я обдумал много вариант, но вот до Вашего почему-то не додумался. Вполне неплохая идея для моего проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Не проще было написать так:

h2{
тут стили
}

и этот класс применится ко всем h2 - тегам

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Для всех чтоб пременить просто в css h2 без точки и стили будут пременены для всех h2

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как, по БЭМ такие общие стили делать не совсем правильно. Блок должен быть независимым, чтобы его можно было сделать без проблем перенести куда угодно.

Мне кажется, было бы логичнее реализовать ваш второй вариант: то есть создать отдельный класс, например `.content__title`

Еще можете спросить в [форуме БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/forum/).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Да, вы полностью правы, блоки должны быть независимы. Я еще многое не выкупил, но буду учиться дальше.